# Stack Exchange scripts not working

Tags: support, javascript, google-chrome, ajax

Recently I've run into a problem where scripts don't work on Stack Exchange. Things like the drop-down menu, comment buttons, voting, etc., seem to be broken for me. However, this only happens when I'm logged in, and seemingly only takes effect a certain time after I log in.

Clearing my cookies and logging in allows me to temporarily use the drop-down menu and comment, but whenever I exit out of the tab and then come back, if I'm still logged in everything is broken.

What is the solution to fix this? I don't have `noscript`, and I've checked my adblock and ran virus scans. Nothing has come up that could possibly cause this.

Comment: What browser are you using? And do you see any JavaScript errors when this happens?

Comment: I'm using chrome, and I didn't see any javascript errors. 
What's really crazy is that it started working instantly after I asked this question. I'm not entirely sure what that means, though.

Comment: Which version of Chrome & OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Yet again, I have to point to extremely broken / buggy caching in Chrome 11 and beyond.

Clear your browser cache and try again.

Comment: I've done that several times. Before this question, it would continually break, even after that.